# microsoftreportviewer using multiple tables

Tags: c#, windows, forms, reportviewer

I have a windows form that I am using a microsoftreportviewer on and I can do this sucessfully with one dataset.  Suppose I have tables table1,table2, and table3, how would I add all of these to the reportviewer programatically on ReportViewer_Load?  Thanks!

Note: All these tables have DIFFERENT columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to select any one by their name at a time and then bind it to report ? If that's what you are looking for then the code below might help you :

```
private DataTable GetData(string tableName)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        string query = "Select * from something";
        OdbcDataAdapter da = new OdbcDataAdapter(query, conn);
        da.Fill(ds);
        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[tableName];
        return dt;
    }
//You can fill the dataset once and then just get the table by table name. No necessary that you have to fill the dataset every time to get tables 

    private void RunReportViewer()
    {
        this.ReportViewer1.Reset();
        this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("Report.rdlc");
        ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("#_your_table_Name", GetData());
        this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
        this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
        this.ReportViewer1.DataBind();
        this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
    }
```